# I wan to extract all the links inside the div tag with class span12 and <p>Automotive Brands</p>

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.fcagroup.com/en-US/group/regions/Pages/northamerica.aspx");
                var foundAppropriateMetaTag = false;
                var divs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'span12')]");
                var linksOnPage = from lnks in divs.Descendants()
                                  where lnks.Name == "a" &&
                                  lnks.Attributes["href"] != null &&
                                 lnks.InnerText.Trim().Length > 0
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      Url = lnks.Attributes["href"].Value,
                                      Text = lnks.InnerText,

                                  };
```

I have tried above but it is extracting all the links from all the divs with class span12 but I only want links inside div that contains Automotive Brands PTag. Help me to achieve that.

Comment: What stops you from filtering `divs` further? It seems you already know what the conditions are.

Comment: Actually its extracting all the links from all the divs with this class but I want the links of the divs only in which P tag Automotive Brands is there and want to ignore rest of the links @MarkusDeibel

Comment: I would filter `divs` step by step using mutliple linq queries. Once you get the desired result you can try to combine them. Depending on how complex the single query than gets you might want to keep the separate ones for better readability, though. Also a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below 
`var divs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'span12')]");`
you can add the following code.

```cs
var autoNodes = new List<HtmlNode>();
foreach (var div in divs)
{
    if (div.ChildNodes.Any(c => c.InnerText.Contains("Automotive Brands")))
    {
         autoNodes.Add(div);
    }
}

var links = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
foreach (var node in autoNodes)
{
     var nodeLinks = node.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.Equals("a")
                                                  && c.Attributes["href"].Value.Contains("brands")
                                                  && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.InnerText.Trim()));
     links.AddRange(nodeLinks.Select(nl =>
                     new KeyValuePair<string, string>(nl.Attributes["href"].Value, nl.InnerText)));

}
```

This is the readable version.

You can transform it to

```
var autoNodes = divs.Where(div => div.ChildNodes.Any(c => c.InnerText.Contains("Automotive Brands"))).ToList();
```

if you like.

Comment: This is good but now how to get links inside autonodes because it gives me error on descendents in my earlier code @Markus Deibel

Comment: I have updated my answer with some code that gives you the link and text as a list of KeyValue pairs. You should probably move this into an actual Dictionary ;)